# json parsing not working on mozilla firefox browser

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I have written $.ajax function to make API call. But the result is displayed only on chrome browser. The result of the API call does not gets displayed on firefox browser. Also the ajax call does not work at all in IE browser. Can anybody please advise why this issue is coming.

Following is the code i have used:

```
var seriesurl = "http://t2json.tgoservices.com/818746/PrinterManufacturers/21/PrinterSeries";

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: seriesurl
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        var items = item.PrinterSeries.Items;

        for (var a = 0; a < items.length; a++) {
            var id;

            $("#content1").html('<a class="manufacturer" onclick="getprinter(' + items[a].Id + ',' + n + ');" id="' + items[a].Id + '" style="cursor:pointer;" >' + items[a].Name + '</a>');
        }
    });
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    $('#status').html(textStatus);
    $('#content').html('(failed)');
});
```

Comment: have you checked the response body in firebug?

Comment: yes following is the response in firebug:
{"T2Json":{"version":"1.1.0","PrinterSeries":{"Items":[{"Id":"70","Name":"DCP Series"},{"Id":"72","Name":"FAX Series"},{"Id":"74","Name":"HL Series"},{"Id":"76","Name":"Intellifax"},{"Id":"77","Name":"MFC Series"}]}}}

Comment: would you mind showing your html code as well

Comment: Did you check Same Origin Policy Violation

Comment: The server does not seem to support CORS, so you cannot make an Ajax call directly to the server from JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the issue stems from not defining the dataType on the initial ajax request.

```
if(!window.console) console = {log:function(){}};
function getData(){
var seriesurl = "http://t2json.tgoservices.com/818746/PrinterManufacturers/21/PrinterSeries";
$.get(seriesurl,function(data){ 
    console.log(data);

    var items = data.T2Json.PrinterSeries.Items;
    console.log(items);

    for(var a = 0; a < items.length; a++) {
        $("#content1").append('<a class="manufacturer" onclick="getprinter('+items[a].Id+');" id="'+items[a].Id+'" style="cursor:pointer;" >'+ items[a].Name + '</a><br>');
    }

},'json'); //--dataType definition (json, jsonp, html, xml, etc...)
}
```

Please note that I modified your code slightly. There is an "n" variable within your generated anchor tags that was not defined in the code snippet, so I removed for the example.

If you prefer to use the ajax shorthand, you just need to add the dataType:json setting.